# Proof that the induced class function $\theta^G$ is a character if $\theta$ is a representation on subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

In [these lecture notes](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_5.html) by Daniel Bump on Induced Characters I have a question on the proof of Theorem 2.5.1. If $H$ is a subgroup of the finite group $G$ and $(\pi, V)$ a representation of $H$, i.e. a homomorphism $\pi : H \to GL(V)$, then the theorem states a way to get a representation $(\theta^G, V^G)$ on the whole of $G$.

Here if $\theta$ is a function on $H$, the extension to $G$ is done by defining
$$
 \dot \theta(g) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \theta(g) & \mbox{ if } g \in H,\\
                 0 & \mbox{ otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$
and then
$$
 \theta^G(g) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{x\in G} \dot \theta(xgx^{-1}).
$$
The theorem states:

**Theorem:** Let $\theta$ be the character of the representation $V$ of $H$. The function $\theta^G$ is the character of a representation of $G$. Its degree is $[G : H]\theta(1)$. If $\chi$ is any character of $G$, and $\chi_H$ is its restriction to $H$, then
$$
 \langle \theta^G, \chi \rangle_G = \langle \theta, \chi_H \rangle_H.
$$
In its proof almost everything is clear, how the above formula is verified and so on, but then in the part where he proves that $\theta^G$ is a character I do not understand whats happening. There he states:

> It remains to be proved that $\theta^G$ is a character. Let $(\pi_1, V_1),
>   \cdots, (\pi_h, V_h)$ be representatives of the isomorphism classes of the
>     irreducible $G$-modules, and $\chi_1, \cdots, \chi_h$ be their characters.
>     Since the $\chi_i$ are a basis of the complex vector space of class
>     functions, and since $\theta^G$ is a class function, we can write
>     $$ \theta^G = \sum_{i = 1}^h a_i \chi_i, $$
>     where the $a_i$ are complex numbers, and if we can show that $a_i$ are
>     nonnegative integers, it will follow that $\theta^G$ is a character, namely
>     it will be the character of the representation on the module
>     $$ a_1 V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_h V_h . $$

I do not understand, why if the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers, then $\theta^G$ is a character? And why is it the character of the representation on the module $a_1 V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_h V_h$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the trace is an additive invariant of a representation.  If $V= \bigoplus a_iV_i$ is a $G$-module, then for each $g\in G$ $$\chi_V(g) = Tr(\pi(g)) = Tr(\sum_i a_i\pi_i(g)) = \sum a_i Tr(\pi_i(g)) = \sum a_i\chi_i(g). $$

In view of the comments below, let me supplant my answer with the rest of the story (I am working over $\mathbb{C}$ from now on).

The character of a $G$-representation is the class function associated to $\pi:G\curvearrowright V$ given by $\chi_V(g) = Tr(\pi(g))$.  We saw above that a non-negative integer linear combination of the $\chi_i$ associated to the irreducible representations is a character.

Conversely, every character is a non-negative integer linear combination of the $\chi_i$.  To show this: let $V$ be a $G$-space.  By complete reducibility, $V$ is a direct sum of irreducibles.  Gathering multiplicities, $V\simeq \oplus a_i V_i$ where $a_i$ are the multiplicities, possibly zero, and $V_i$ runs through irreps.  Then the same computation as above shows that $\chi_V$ is a non-negative integer linear combination of the $\chi_i$.  The $\chi_i$ are independent because they are orthogonal with respect to the usual inner product, so the expression of $\chi_V$ is unique.

This shows that the set $C$ of characters of the various complex representations of $G$ are precisely the non-negative cone in the integer lattice spanned by the $\chi_i$: $$C=\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\chi_i.$$

Comment: But what has this to do with the non-negativity of the $a_i$?

Comment: @Stefan The $a_i$ are the multiplicities of the irreducibles in the direct sum decomposition of $V$. You cannot have an irreducible appearing a negative number of times.

Comment: @Stefan recall that $cV$ is shorthand for $V⊕⋯⊕V$ $c$ times. If the coefficients are non-negative integers, you can interpret them as multiplicities and associate the character to that direct sum. If they are not non-negative integers, you cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what seems to be implicit in your computations, and what I was not aware of, is that for a given $G$-module the character on it (and the representations up to similarity) are unique. My ignorance of this fact is also present in other questions of mine. I would be glad if you can point to (or give) a proof of this fact, as the lecture notes I am working with (the ones linked in my question) do not mention that (they just state as Prop. 2.3.2. that for a $G$-module we can find some representation inducing the $G$-module, but not its uniqueness up to similarity)?

Comment: @Stefan Equivalence of $G$-modules is the same as equivalence of representations: intertwining by an invertible linear map (unitary,rational etc. if the representation is such).  To show uniqueness of the character, use the fact that the trace is conjugation invariant and therefore unchanged by intertwining.